# shell script delete file before creating file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following script,

```
#!/bin/bash

for data in $(someprogram withsomeargument)
do                      
      IFS=',' read -r -a dataArray<<< "$data"
      NAME="${dataArray[0]}"
      DATE="${dataArray[3]}" 

      echo "$DATE" >> ~/Documents/testing/files/dates.txt
done
```

it saves dates line by line into the dates.txt folder.

I want to add `rm ~/Documents/testing/files/dates.txt` at the front to make sure that there is no file before the script runs, but when I run it multiple times, the file doesn't get deleted, it just keeps appending the data from the previous run.

How do I make sure the dates.txt file is deleted before the script is run if the file exists?

Comment: Where did you try to add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `>> ~/Documents/testing/files/dates.txt` after `echo` and

append `> ~/Documents/testing/files/dates.txt` after `done`. No need for `rm`.

```
for data in $(someprogram withsomeargument)
do                      
      IFS=',' read -r -a dataArray<<< "$data"
      NAME="${dataArray[0]}"
      DATE="${dataArray[3]}" 

      echo "$DATE"
done > ~/Documents/testing/files/dates.txt
```